# I would like to create Menu with categories and sub categories

Tags: css

I would like to create menu with categories and sub categories

For example you can check here www.boots.com

Can any one give me suggestion

Thanks
Raju

Comment: Do a [google search for "css drop down menu tutorial"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=css+drop+down+menu+tutorial&oq=css+drop+down+menu+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g-c3g-b3g-bm3&aql=1&gs_sm=e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial, **css mega drop down menu**

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Example here

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html

Comment: Hi Yasir,    Thank you very much for your link. It seems like my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and look right [here](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/11279-jquery-sliding-navigation-v10/)

Nice jQuery menu plugin, easy to use